# Manipulating the triangle inequality to compare two sides

Tags: vector-analysis, triangle-inequality

With $\mathbf x$ and $\mathbf y$ two vectors, the triangle inequality can be written as:

$$
|\mathbf x|-|\mathbf y| \le |\mathbf x + \mathbf y|\le |\mathbf x|+|\mathbf y| \tag{A}
$$

which can be broken down into a system of inequalities (labelled as (1) and (2)):

\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
|\mathbf x|-|\mathbf y| \le |\mathbf x + \mathbf y| \\
|\mathbf x + \mathbf y|\le |\mathbf x|+|\mathbf y|  
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

then, with the assumption of $|\mathbf y|>0$, (1)-(2) yields:

$$
|\mathbf x| \le |\mathbf x + \mathbf y| \tag{B}
$$

- But is this in fact true? Is (B) a direct consequence of (A) when $|\mathbf y|>0$? or is (B) is invalid because (1)-(2) is not allowed as it is not obvious if the subtraction preserves the inequality?

This question arose during my attempt to [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3999026), where I build triangles from 3 points on a line in order to try and show which point is the last one (to no avail so far).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, we cannot subtract inequalities in the following way:
$$
a \leq b\\
c\leq d\\
\implies a-c\leq b-d $$
For example, take $a=3,b=4,c=1,d=3$ to see that it's wrong. I think this is what you did to obtain what you have. So
$$|\mathbf x|\leq |\mathbf x+\mathbf y| $$
is wrong.
A counterexample in $\mathbb{R}^2$: $\mathbf x=(1,0),\mathbf y=(-1,0)$.

Comment: Can I suggest you "like" one of these answers? Either mine or bjorn93's. Perhaps bjorn93's as it makes the error more explicit.

Answer (score 1):

(B) does not follow from (1)-(2). For a very simple counter-example, work in the 1-dimensional space of real numbers and take **x**=3, **y**=-2.

Comment: But the question is in the context of vectors and their norms, is the 1D analogy accurate here?

Comment: Real numbers are a very simple (one-dimensional) type of vector. In any case it should be easy to devise e.g  a 2-dimensional counter-example. Why do you think (B) follows from (1)-(2)?